# Fiware ContextBroker Entity with Array

Tags: arrays, fiware, fiware-orion

Is it possible create an entity in Fiware, where a specific attribute will be send as an array? Something like that? Having multiple pressure sensors inside a room where I would like to receive them in one update?!

So this is basically creating the Entity

```
{
  "id": "Room1",
  "type": "Room",
  "temperature": {
    "value": 23,
    "type": "Float"
  },
  "pressure": {
    "value": 720,
    "type": "Integer"
  }
}
```

and I would like to receive updates in one update message with all pressure information inside this "Entity"

```
{
  "id": "Room1",
  "type": "Room",
  "temperature": {
    "value": 23,
    "type": "Float"
  },
  "pressure": [{
    "value": 720,
    "type": "Integer"
  },
  {
    "value": 500,
    "type": "Integer"
  },
 ]
}
```

Thanks in advance!

-pd

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same you are proposing but you can have all the values in an array. Something like this:

```
{
  "id": "Room1",
  "type": "Room",
  "temperature": {
    "value": 23,
    "type": "Float"
  },
  "pressure": {
    "value": [720, 500],
    "type": "Integer"
  }
}
```

or, if you need type information in each one, you could try:

```
{
  "id": "Room1",
  "type": "Room",
  "temperature": {
    "value": 23,
    "type": "Float"
  },
  "pressure": {
    "value": [
       {"value": 720, "type": "Integer"},
       {"value": 500, "type": "Integer"}
    ],
    "type": "Array"
  }
}
```